# PresentViewController with custom animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to present view controller with UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animation where source controller disappear from 1 alpha to 0 and destination controller appear from 0 alpha to 1

I'd like to use

```
presentViewController: animated: completion:
```

I've tried:

In source controller

```
UIStoryboard *st = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
PopViewController *pop =  [st instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:name];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pop];
nav.navigationBarHidden = YES;


[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
self.view.alpha = 0.f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
  [self presentViewController:nav animated:NO completion:nil];
}];
```

In destination controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.view.alpha = 0.f;
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
self.view.alpha = 1.f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

but controllers disappear and appear not at the same time

Comment: Checkout Transition Style "Cross Dissolve". Should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pavel, for example

```
-(void)goToViewControllerAction
{
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    [transition setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
    transition.duration = 1.5; 
    [transition setType:kCATransitionFade];

    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"someAnimation"];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"backPopsegue" sender:nil];// Here your push or performSegue transition

    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Don't remember to use QuartzCore)

You can customize your transition like you want, there are a lot of different settings in it....

Comment: This is almost what I need. But should be UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animation and duration 0.5 sec

Comment: @PavelTychinin sorrr))  look at my answer, i correct them\

Comment: @PavelTychinin may be like this> transition.duration = 1.5;

Comment: @PavelTychinin if you have some problem with transition i can understand it for you on Russian))

Comment: I'm Russian) If u're not hard, how can we connect?